# celery worker refusing to deserialise untrusted content type of application/json

Tags: python, json, rabbitmq, celery, amqp

I have a distributed setup where i am using RabbitMQ as the message broker and celery as the distributed task queue. 
A RabbitMQ java client pushes json data into the message broker
ex:

> {"id":"95a67132-0a47-4d44-80bd-7a8725528254","args":[],"task":"app.task.add","kwargs":[]}

with content-type: application/json, content-encoding: utf-8 (set using a custom MessagePostProcessor implementation)

on Celery side i have tasks.py like:

```
from celery import Celery
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://<broker credentials>@<ip>//')
app.config_from_object('celeryconfig')
@app.task
def add():
    print "done"
@app.task
def addX(x):
    print "done addx"
```

and a celeryconfig.py like:

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue
from kombu.serialization import registry

CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
BROKER_HOST = <ip address of broker> #IP address of the server running RabbitMQ and Celery
BROKER_URL='amqp://<broker credentials>@<ip>'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'
CELERY_IMPORTS=("tasks",)
CELERY_DEFAULT_QUEUE = <queue name>
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['application/json']
CELERY_QUEUES = (
   Queue('default', Exchange('exchange'), routing_key='default'),
)
registry.enable('application/json')
```

but when the celery worker tries to decode the json object pushed into message broker its giving me this error:

```
[2016-01-12 17:47:56,602: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Can't decode message body: ContentDisallowed('Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type application/json; charset=utf-8 (application/json; charset=utf-8)',) [type:u'application/json; charset=utf-8' encoding:u'utf-8' headers:{}]

body: u'{"id":"78094130-9e45-4b0e-9418-e249219e8e65","args":[],"task":"app.task.add","kwargs":[]}' (89b)
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/tech/messaging/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/messaging.py", line 592, in _receive_callback
   decoded = None if on_m else message.decode()
 File "/Users/tech/messaging/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/message.py", line 142, in decode
   self.content_encoding, accept=self.accept)
 File "/Users/tech/messaging/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/serialization.py", line 174, in loads
   raise self._for_untrusted_content(content_type, 'untrusted')
ContentDisallowed: Refusing to deserialize untrusted content of type application/json; charset=utf-8 (application/json; charset=utf-8)
```

can someone help me out as where i am making mistake?

EDIT:
on suggestion from scytale

I tried putting 'application/data' and 'application/text' and the error changed from 'Refusing to deserialize' to this:

```
[2016-01-12 20:59:34,903: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: u'{"id":"03339160-3c43-4327-99ce-a733e58b16b2","args":[],"task":"app.task.add","kwargs":[]}' (89b)
{content_type:u'application/data' content_encoding:u'utf-8'
 delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': u'None5', 'redelivered': False, 'routing_key': u'exportToExcelQueue', 'delivery_tag': 1, 'exchange': u'exchange'} headers={}}
```

i peeked into the code of celery.worker.consumer.py and found out that its looking for 'task' in message header and when not found throwing an 'UNKNOWN_FORMAT' exception. I then set the header of message like this on java client side:

> message.getMessageProperties().setHeader("task", "app.task.add");

Still the same error

Answer (score 3):

i got the issue resolved by changing :

> CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json','application/text']

and adding

> registry.enable('json')
>
> registry.enable('application/text')

in celeryconfig.py. The final format looked something like this:

```
from kombu import Exchange, Queue
from kombu.serialization import registry

CELERY_IMPORTS = ('tasks')
CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = False
BROKER_HOST = <IP address of the server running RabbitMQ and Celery>
BROKER_URL='amqp://<broker credentials>@<ip>'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'amqp://'
CELERY_IMPORTS=("tasks",)
CELERY_DEFAULT_EXCHANGE_TYPE = 'direct'
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json','application/text']
CELERY_QUEUES = (
 Queue('exportToExcelQueue', Exchange('exchange'), routing_key='default'),
)
registry.enable('json')
registry.enable('application/text')
```

I have also changed the message header back to 'application/json' and the celery message to the format:

```
{
    "id": "a72d85f4-499a-4428-a5ab-29290788d826",
    "args": [],
    "task": "tasks.add"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check out the [code](https://github.com/celery/kombu/blob/v3.0.29/kombu/serialization.py#L172) - `kombu/serialization.py`

```
TRUSTED_CONTENT = frozenset(['application/data', 'application/text'])

...

class SerializerRegistry(object):
"""The registry keeps track of serialization methods."""

def loads(self, data, content_type, content_encoding,
          accept=None, force=False, _trusted_content=TRUSTED_CONTENT):
    content_type = content_type or 'application/data'
    if accept is not None:
        if content_type not in _trusted_content \
                and content_type not in accept:
            raise self._for_untrusted_content(content_type, 'untrusted')
```

i.e. the java client needs to use `content-type: application/data` or `content-type: application/text`

Comment: i tried your suggestion by changing the content-type to application/data or application/text. The error has changed but now i am receiving this error:

[2016-01-12 20:59:34,903: WARNING/MainProcess] Received and deleted unknown message. Wrong destination?!?

The full contents of the message body was: body: u'{"id":"03339160-3c43-4327-99ce-a733e58b16b2","args":[],"task":"app.task.add","kwargs":[]}' (89b)
{content_type:u'application/data' content_encoding:u'utf-8'
 delivery_info:{'consumer_tag': u'None5', 'redelivered': False, .....

Comment: i peeked into the celery.worker.consumer.py code and found out that this error comes when format is unknown. It looks for 'task' in message headers like this:
message.headers['task'].
any insight on this?

Comment: please don't paste code into SO comments - without formatting they are unreadable. Please open a new question. At a glance it looks like your message is incomplete - probably lacking routing information.